# Need a bootstrap push/pull themeplate code

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, optimization

I'm trying to use the push and pull classes to realize a particular responsive bootstrap themeplate and although I have sought and made references to various examples to try to figure out how I could relize what I exactly wanted, I have not been able to reach a valid conclusion that not overly make dirty the code. I would also be fine just with a simple explanation of the precautions that must be taken in the implementation of the code to do so reach this result. ty in advance. Basically this is my structure, the way i tryed to solve the my needs.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-14">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                <div>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <p></p>
                <div>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                <div>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-14">
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-14">
        <div>
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-14">
        <div class="col-md-14 col-sm-14 col-xs-14">
            <a class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" href="#"></a>
            <p class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8"></p><a class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EXAMPLE**

[image]

Comment: Do you have a custom build of Bootstrap? Normally there are 12 columns, not 14. I'm not sure you can get that layout using Bootstrap 3's grid system. Maybe with Bootstrap 4. Which uses flexbox which allows you to reorder elements, doubt it though.

Comment: @hungerstar: [`How to customize the grid system for Bootstrap 3`](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system)

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu notice I asked if it was customized. Just clarifying as the current code is a bit _"wonky"_ and atypical with its implementation of the grid system.

Comment: @hungerstar, oh, I thought you said *" Normally there are 12 columns, not 14. I'm not sure you can get that layout using Bootstrap 3's grid system"*. My bad.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu what exactly is your point? I asked for clarification if it was a custom build. Then re-clarified in my next comment as to why I was clarifying that it was a custom build. Anyways, customizing the number of columns, size of gutters etc. has nothing to do with how the grid system is structured and intended to be use vs the layout the OP is going for. I'm pretty sure you can't go from the layout on the left to the layout on the right when resizing the viewport with BS3. And probably not BS4. But if someone can prove me wrong, great! I'd love to know how!

Comment: @hungerstar, you're gonna make me answer, just to prove it can be done, aren't you? :) SalvatoreImprota, have you customized your version of Bootstrap by changing the number of columns? If so, could you create a [mcve] linking the customized version of Bootstrap? I'll be happy to work on that.

Comment: **LOL, absolutely!** I didn't mean you can't have 14, 16, or 500 columns. I meant having the layout on the left changing to the layout on the right when resizing. I'm sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: @hungerstar you were right. I thought it was possible because I didn't notice the 2nd inversion (the one between `2` and `3`). It's not doable without javascript atm, It will be doable using CSS grid though.

Comment: @hungerstat i did it using only html and css, but i i have complicated too much the positioning of content and that's why i'm looking for one better solution also considering the implementation of some script. the themeplate has 14 columns for respond better to exchange of proportions during the shrinkage of the window. you would like to have the link of my build of bootstrap that i have used to try to seek one solution?